# how to prevent output wrapping in RMarkdown html_fragment

Tags: html, r-markdown, line-breaks, carriage-return

I have some RMarkdown code that generates html_fragments that are used as the basis of emails. When last run (January 2022) the resulting HTML files (when viewed in a text editor) had each paragraph tag on a separate (long) line. When I run the exact same code today, the paragraph tags are wrapped with carriage returns/line feeds at 70-100 characters, producing the paragraph tag spread over multiple lines, e.g.

> < p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
> industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever
> since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
> scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
> five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
> remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
> the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
> more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
> including versions of Lorem Ipsum.< /p>

This is a problem for subsequent steps in the pipeline which require the paragraph tags in unbroken lines.

Does anyone know what has changed to cause the insertion of carriage returns and linefeeds in the HTML file? And is there a way to revert back to the single line output? I have tried setting width in an initial opt_chunks$set statement but this does not appear to affect plain text outside code chunks.

Example code

temp.Rmd

```
---
title: Demo
output: 
  html_fragment:
    self_contained: false
---

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

output.R

```
    rmarkdown::render(input = 'code/temp.Rmd',
                      output_file = 'linereturnproblem.html',
                      output_dir = 'results/messages',
                      encoding="UTF-8", quiet = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour was caused by Pandoc wrapping the text when converting from md to HTML. The solution to this (thanks Philipp Boersch-Supan) was to add pandoc_args: "--wrap=none" into the YAML header:

```
---
title: Demo
output: 
  html_fragment:
    pandoc_args: "--wrap=none"
    self_contained: false
---
```

I still don't know what change in my environment over the last year caused wrapping to switch from off by default to on by default.